# Apache flink installation with HA

Tags: apache-flink

Is it mandatory to have hadoop set to install flink service in High Availability mode.

If yes can you please explain how it is related.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

No, Flink does not require hadoop for high availability.

Since version 1.4, there is a [hadoop-free release of Flink](https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html), so Flink itself does not require Hadoop. As for high availability (HA), see [the Flink HA documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/jobmanager_high_availability.html), which explains how to setup HA for standalone clusters (and for yarn, but that implies hadoop).

You will also need a distributed file system for a robust Flink setup. HDFS is commonly used for this, but S3 and CEPH are alternatives that don't require hadoop.